# How can I make my program execute a function from a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: python, keyboard, shortcut

How can I do it, even if my application.exe is not the focused window ?

For example, like the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut... Works everywhere...

I want that <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> does a function, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> does another one, and so on...

Comment: This article seems relevant: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like [this?](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [pyHook](http://mindtrove.info/articles/monitoring-global-input-with-pyhook/).

Comment: seems exactly what I need, but I don't know exactly how to do it.. Any example with some case similar to mine?

Answer (score 1):

I have a pyHook example on my site. http://fadedbluesky.com/2011/using-pyhook-to-block-windows-key/

I originally wrote this to block keys in a game written using pygame.  You should be able to easily adapt it to other windows programs.